# How to aggregate IEnumerable<string> to string using Linq Aggregate function

Tags: linq-to-sql, aggregate

I have `Ienumerable<string>` collection that I want to concatenate into a single string with delimitor ;

for instance {"One","Two","Three"} -> "One;Two;Three;"

is it possible to do using the following function?

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(){"One","Two","Three"};
list.Aggregate<String>((x,y) => x + String.Format("{0};",y));
```

I have tried also this code:

```
list.Aggregate<String>((x,y) => String.Format("{0};{1}",x,y));
```

both samples didn't work.

EDIT: I see that it is not possible to do what I wanted using Linq-2-sql or Aggregate function in Linq-2-sql.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/dac496c0-5b37-43ba-a499-bb8eff178706/

EDIT2: the workaround I used is to go over the items returned by the original linq query...and copies them to a new list and do the join as suggested in the answers below on a  linq object and not linq-2-sql object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx) for this. If you're using .NET4 then you can use [the overload that takes an `IEnumerable<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) directly:

```
string joined = string.Join(";", list);
```

If you're using an older version of the framework then you'll need to use [the overload that takes a `string[]` array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) instead, converting your collection to an array first if necessary:

```
string joined = string.Join(";", list.ToArray());
```

**EDIT...**

Of course, if you really want to use `Aggregate` for some reason then there's nothing stopping you. If so, it's usually recommended to build your string using a `StringBuilder` rather than multiple string allocations:

```
string joined = list.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                               (sb, s) => sb.Append(s).Append(';'),
                               sb => (sb.Length > 0) ? sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - 1)
                                                     : "");
```

Comment: this doesn't work i get the following error down the road:
Method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: @Itay: Sorry, I completely missed your LINQ-to-SQL tag. This will only work with LINQ-to-Objects.

Comment: it's ok, i have edited the tag to linq-to-sql because i reliazed it makes a different

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using below code

```
list.Aggregate((i, j) => i + ";" + j);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide an initializer, otherwise the first element will not have a `;` added to it:

```
list.Aggregate<String>("", (x,y) => x + String.Format("{0};",y));
```

Comment: On this code i get the following error:
"The query operator 'Aggregate' is not supported."

Comment: Microsoft / Joe Albahari: The Aggregate operator is not supported in LINQ to SQL because there is no way to translate arbitrary aggregations to SQL. I can't imagine this will change anytime soon.

Comment: Your original question didn't state linq-to-sql.